# Minimal domain for sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I would like to use [Sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/latest/index.html) for my own project and for that I want to create a new sphinx [domain](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/latest/domains.html). But I have serious trouble getting started. My minimal sphinx domain would allow only a single instruction called 'command':

```
.. xx:command:: Somecommand
```

I can't find any introduction to writing sphinx domains "on the internet", only some ready to run domains for ruby, erlang etc. Can someone advise me on how to get started?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checkout the [reStructuredText domain](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/93b1a4e9b789/sphinx/domains/rst.py) in the Sphinx source code, it's fairly simple and should get you started. You may also find some good examples in the [sphinx-contrib source](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/src).

Comment: The only problem with recommending the reStructuredText domain is that you then get terminology being used to refer to the reStructuredText source as used by Sphinx and the reStructuredText domain. You can still figure it out, but it may be a bit harder in that respect than others.

Comment: I have copied the ReST domain and changed it. Still lots of open issues, but this should be part of other questions. Thanks!